# Index match match 2 columns

Tags: excel-formula

I’m having difficulty with an index match match formula which I thought would be quite easy to achieve

I have an array C1:M67 in row one I want to find the value stated in A2 **Momentum** then the value in B2 **MOCHA** in the corresponding column. Then return the value in the 2 adjacent cells in the example below I want to return the value **KM98** and **KM98/UK/MM/02**

If I were to change the value in A2 to **Mid-Range** I would want to return **KM93** and **M98/UK/02/MRANGE**

[image]

Many thanks for you help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an INDEX/MATCH inside the VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP($B$2,INDEX($C:$M,0,MATCH($A$2,$C$1:$M$1,0)):INDEX($C:$M,0,MATCH($A$2,$C$1:$M$1,0)+2),2,FALSE)
```

This will return the sku.  For the Code change the `,2,` to `,3,`